# Firefox can't establish connection to the server http://Localhost/signalr/connect.. in MVC 5 VS 2013

Tags: signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to develop chat application using Asp.net signalr. I am using same code which is given here

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

It simply worked on Html page. but when i do it in MVC 5 it stopped working. 
in firefox i get

1. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents...  And after that
2. Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send() @ localhost:16790/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js:530

In Chrome nothing works it says "Refused to execute script from 'localhost:16790/signalr/hubs' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled"
In IE 10 also it doesnt work either. Please help..

Comment: Update your packages in the MVC 5 project. There's a bug in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb beta1 you'll need the beta2 version.